# how do i change a variable value when it gets tangled in various getintervals?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little jquery script for a stop motion animation. It uses moment.js to get the time and then does some math to get a "frame" number and then does some padding to match it to a filename in my directory, spits that into an img src and then iterates +1. I have two setInterval functions going-one that controls the frame rate (getframe) and one that controls how often the client checks for the proper time (gettime).

I've just discovered there are a bunch of dead frames in my directory though-- image files that I want to skip over but I can't just delete without screwing up my whole sequence, to be exact I want to my script to skip from image-029399.jpg to image-031170.jpg. Because a client might log in in the middle of that dead space, I was thinking I should have some kind of statement like if (frame>=29399 && <=31170; {frame=31171};) but I can't quite figure out how to insert that into my code without making everything stop working... below is my code:

```
window.onload = $(function () {
    gettime();

    setinterval(gettime,10000);   
    setInterval(getframe,580); 

    var frame;

    function gettime() {
        now = moment().zone('+0045');

        if (now.hour()<=17) {
            now =now.subtract('day',1)
        }

        if (now.hour() >= 18) {
            now = now.subtract('hour', 18).subtract('minute', 30);
        } 
        else {
            now = now.add('hour', 6).subtract('minute', 30);
        }  

        frame = ((now.hour() * 3600) + (now.minute() * 60) + now.second()) * 2 +7463;
    } 


    function getframe() { 
        var framestr = frame? frame.toString() : "";

        function pad (str, max) {
            return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
        }

        framerun = pad (framestr,6);
        var src = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/combined11/image-"+ framerun +".jpg";
        framerun1=parseInt(framerun);
        $("#frame_placeholder").attr("src", src);

        frame=framerun1 += 1;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it in the place where you set frame, i.e. `gettime`.  Add this below your `frame =`... line:

```
function gettime() {
    now = moment().zone('+0045');

    if (now.hour()<=17) {
        now =now.subtract('day',1)
    }

    if (now.hour() >= 18) {
        now = now.subtract('hour', 18).subtract('minute', 30);
    } 
    else {
        now = now.add('hour', 6).subtract('minute', 30);
    }  

    frame = ((now.hour() * 3600) + (now.minute() * 60) + now.second()) * 2 +7463;
    if (frame >= 29399) {
       frame += 1771;
    }
}
```

Now, why?

First you change it where you're setting frame because it's the problem of the settor, not the gettor.  And of course, since you're recalculating it each time, make sure you put the new code after the recalculation.

At first, I considered what you did: `if (frame >= 29399 && frame <= 31170) frame = 31171;`, but that essentially makes the program hang on the same frame for 1771 frames.

Then I considered `if (frame >= 29399 && frame <= 31170) frame += 1771`, but that's even worse - that would jump to the right frame, advance for 1771 frames, and then jump back to frame 31171, which isn't desired.

No, all you want to do is skip a gap, and *all frames after that gap must make the same jump*.  So as soon as you hit the low side of the gap, just add the distance (31170 - 29399) of the gap to all values.

**EDIT** Actually, I don't know enough about the rest of your system to know if this is the right answer.  If other things depend on the value of `frame`, you actually may want to make the change in the gettor without changing the base value of frame:

```
function getframe() { 
    var framestr = frame ? (frame >= 29399) ? (frame + 1771).toString() : frame.toString() : "";
```

And depending on what behavior you want in the deadzone, you may need to use any of the other function variations I discussed.
        var framestr = frame? frame.toString() : "";

Comment: yours is an elegant solution because it accounts for all the frames after the dead zone but the problem is I'm working with a list of files that is already set and that I can't change without a great amount of trouble. So I'm basically looking for a hack that will just jump the deadzone and then continue on-- basically making the total animation shorter (in total duration) by the length I jumped. I wonder if i just changed the (frame >= 29399) part to (frame<=31170 && >=29399) ... if that would work.. basically just capturing stuff in between but not effecting anything after, make sense?

Comment: @user3079080 If you just want to shorten it, you'll want the version I posted.  :-)  Otherwise, think what will happen from 31170 to 31171.  At 31170, you're in the if, so you add the difference and use file 32941.  Then, at 31171, you're out of the if, so you go back in time to file 31171 - which you were at 1772 frames ago!  To shorten, just do it the way I did.  If you have any other gaps, just add another if statement to make the next jump, and so on.

Comment: oh hold on i have just been using the line you put in at the bottom and didn't realize you had suggested that as another potential place to change things not as the solution

Comment: works just as you said! perfect-- thank you...will come in handy wherever i need it here!

Comment: because i rather learn than just "get a solution"-- I'm still puzzling over why this doesn't add 1771 frames to every frame>=29399 ...isn't that exactly what it's saying? how does it know to only apply it to the dead zone?

Comment: @user3079080 Always happy to help learning, but I'm not sure how much more I can explain it.  If you want to jump a deadzone, you want everything past the deadzone to reflect the jump. `if (frame >= 29399) { frame += 1771; }` does exactly that.  It doesn't matter if your frame is 29500, 30000, or 30000000 - once you've added the offset ("made the jump"), it has to stay.  Otherwise, if you only do it over a limited range, you'll be backtracking once you're out of that range.  Try it with the `&& <= 31170`, and `console.log` the frame numbers.  You'll see it go to 32941 then down to 31171.

Comment: ah repeating it in that expanded form made it click-- the offset has to be applied to the "frame" variable because the frame variable is being pulled from the time. I had mistaken in my mind the frame variable as just being the frame number in colloquial usage, but since it's tied to time here it's really more like a unit of time. thanks for the extra effort to parse it out. i.e. it has to stay 1771 frames ahead of what the time tells it it should be at from then on out...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the top of `getFrame` would make the most sense, no?

```
function getframe() {
    if (frame && ((frame >= 29399) && (frame <= 31170))) {
        frame = 31171;
    }

    var framestr = frame ? frame.toString() : "";
    // etc.
```